# What does $VARIABLE$ stand for

Tags: bash, nagios

..in the following shell script? 
`$USER1$=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins`

As far as i know variable defining is done as- 
`export USER1=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins`

[Source](http://lena.franken.de/nagios/own_service.html):

> Ok, the command works. Now I have to implement it into Nagios. Because
>   all my "local" command not installed by the package-manager shall be
>   in /usr/lib/nagios/plugins_local I define a $USER2$ variable for this
>   path:

```
# vim resource.cfg
...

# Sets $USER1$ to be the path to the plugins
$USER1$=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins

# my own check-commands live here:
$USER2$=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins_local
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's meant to be interpreted by the shell?

Comment: Whatever it is it is NOT bash/shell script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$USERn$` (more specifically, `$USER1` to `$USER255$`) is the way to declare a [user-defined Macro](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/macrolist.html#user) in Nagios.

See also "[Understanding Macros and how they work](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/macros.html)."

Answer (score 2):

More specifically and more interestingly this is a good way to hide usernames/passwords needed withing database/http checks for instance.

This means that you can attempt soemthing like the following directly in your configuration files and thus you do not fear that you are committing or backing up usernames/passwords.

```
./nrpe -c check_http -H $IP -a $USER1$:$USER2$ -u $LINK
```

An aside: Unfortunetly Nagios only supports up to 32 of the USER variables.